# ASP.NET Control not passing through updated string to code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a bit of an issue I hope you guys can give me a bit of help with.

I have an ASP.NET textbox control.  In my code behind I throw text in there with

```
txtTextbox.Text = variable;
```

Variable being a value I get from a database in earlier lines of code.

So after this, when I edit the text in that text box, in the button click event handler I get the new value with

```
string variable = txtTextbox.Text;
```

The issue is, now this 'new' value is just giving me the original value I placed in the textbox.  Not the one I eddited in my application.

Any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Where are you setting the value ? Can you provide full code of the method your using to set value to textbox

Comment: I will update to add the method for setting the value to the textbox.

Comment: not the custom method I am looking for the page method are you doing in page load ? Please give that I am thinking you are missing post back check

Comment: Yes that is exactly the issue.  I got it all fixed up, can't believe I've been at this for this much time over such a small error.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good, that's what happens sometimes very simple thing eats all day. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Need to check for post back when loading data in to textbox,
 Otherwise data gets binded to textbox when button click happens

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
//load data
}
```